# MVC File Upload save selected file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form with file upload control and it works as expected. However I am having trouble figuring out how to 'save' selected file after submit button has been clicked and model returned from the controller in case of some other invalid fields on the page?
Every time there are errors on the page, user has to browse for the file again. What is best practice way of saving the selection after calling POST on controller?

```
//VIEW
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
  <input id="inputbox" type="file" name="PageUpload" />
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.otherField1)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.otherField2)
}

//CONTROLLER
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyViewModel view)
{
    try
    { ...
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //it is valid save
            return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller", new { id = view.ModelID });
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    return View(view);
}
```

I get all the other fields correctly bound after returning View(view) but not the input control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the user needs to re-select the file is a security measure. You cannot set the value of a file input (if you could, a malicious site could include a few hundred hidden file inputs with "C:\password.doc" etc. and attempt to download sensitive files without the user knowing).

If the model is invalid, you need to save the file before returning the view. In my case, I use a view model that contains an object that includes properties for the file's display name and path. The basic premise is

1. Save the file to a temporary location
2. Update the view model with the files path (to the temporary
   location) and display name
3. Return the view
4. In the view, render the display name (so the user knows which file
   has already been selected) and a hidden input for the `Path`. A
   'delete' button can be associated with this in case the user changes
   their mind and wants to select a different file (use ajax to delete
   the temporary file)
5. If model state is valid when posting, get the temporary path based
   on the value of the hidden input and move the file to its permanent
   location, then save the model and redirect.

Comment: I was afraid it was due to the security that it would not work. However your solution seems like a good way to do it. Thanks @stephen-muecke