# Pass back HttpPostedFileBase from view → controller → back to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My application allow user to upload upload a single image by selecting images with: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Image, new {type = "file"})`. If there was any validation error, I lose its selected file. Therefore I need to temporary save it via `If(!ModelState.IsValid)` code block:

```
public ActionResult Create(MyModel model) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         if(model.Image != null && model.Image.ContentLength > 0) {
         var displayName = Path.GetFileName(model.Image.FileName);
         var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(displayName);
         var fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}", Guid.NewGuid(), fileExtension);
         var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Files"), fileName);
         model.Image.SaveAs(path);
         model.displayName = displayName;
         model.FilePath = path;
         return View(model);
     }
 }
```

I use  `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FilePath)` in view.

`model.Image` type is `HttpPostedFileBase`. I **must** somehow re-gain users selected Image as `HttpPostedFileBase` after `!ModelState.IsValid`, in order to be able to save it in database. Any chance to pass back info inside `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Image, new {type = "file"})`?

[How I later convert HttpPostedFileBase to byte[], in order to store image-data in database.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852102/convert-httppostedfilebase-to-byte)

I don't know how to do it with the tools I have.

**Edit:** model property:

```
public string displayName { get; set; }
public string FilePath { get; set; }
public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }
```

Comment: No you cannot pas it back in `Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Image, new {type = "file"})` for security reasons. (refer [MVC File Upload save selected file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261726/mvc-file-upload-save-selected-file)). You already have a hidden input for the file path, so if `ModelState` is now valid after the resubmit, then get the file you have saved based on the value of the hidden input and convert it to a byte array if your wanting to save it in the database

Comment: e.g. using `byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(model.FilePath);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the value of a file input for security reasons (it can only be set by the user selecting a file in the browser).

In the view, you will need a conditional check to display the file name and path (initially it will be `null`)

```
@if (Model.displayName != null)
{
    <div>@Model.displayName</div> // let the user know that its been uploaded
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FilePath)
}
```

Then in the controller, if `ModelState` is valid, you need to conditionally check the value of `FilePath`. In the case where you submit and `ModelState` is invalid, the value of `FilePath` will now contain the path to the save file when the user re-submits. But in the case where `ModelState` is valid on the initial submit, the value of `FilePath` will be `null`

You controller code needs to be (note, this assumes `MyModel` is actually a view model, and you have an associated data model containing a property `public byte[] Image { get; set; }` for saving the file in the database table

```
public ActionResult Create(MyModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        .... // code as above to save temporary file and return the view
    }
    // Initialize an instance of your data model
    var dataModel = new .... // assumes this contains a property byte[] Image
    if (model.FilePath == null)
    {
        // The code above has never run so read from the HttpPostedFileBase property
        if(model.Image != null && model.Image.ContentLength > 0) {
        {
            MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
            model.Image.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
            dataModel.Image = target.ToArray();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Read from the temporary file
        dataModel.Image = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
        .... // Delete the temporary file
    }
    // Map other properties of your view model to the data model
    // Save and redirect
}
```